# How to import Fixed product taxes in bulk?

Tags: import, magento2.4.3

I tried to import FPT for all my products with an additional column to my CSV import :

wee_tax_variations

and lines like :

name=ecotax,country=FR,state=0,value=1.45,website_id=0

(My attribute name for FPT is ecotax).
The import is accepted but there is no change for the product in admin. Nor in the databas at weee_tax table.
But prices in this import have changed so import is running fine but weee_tax_variations seems not recognized.
Do you know where I am wrong ?

Comment: Hi Did you find solution for this? I am getting exactly same issue

Comment: No solution found. Seems impossible to import. I tried with Magmi but there is also a bug. See here : https://github.com/macopedia/magmi-m2/issues/105